# iTunes Connect only have "Get Started" screen

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

My iTunes Connect only have "Get Started" screen i can't see My Apps Section or any of the normal itunes connect tabs , this account is new and there is no apps yet

[image]

This isn't the first time to use itunes connect but somehow i cant get this account to work fine

Any help on how to pass this screen and start using testflight

Comment: taps 1st "Apps" icon

Comment: then give you screen shot

Comment: as there is no app you will see nothing. you need to add

Comment: then pressed plus button(+)

Comment: there is no apps in the next page it's opening a page that shows the features of itunes connect not the apps , not MY APPS tab

Comment: do you see this http://imgur.com/ZOiZvoE

Comment: do you have your membership account active?

Comment: yes i enrolled to membership like 10 days ago and it's working on xcode but i am not sure whats wrong with itunes connect

Comment: Maybe your account has no authority to access to iTunes Connect. I think the best course of action at this point would be to contact their support.

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @Ivan it's a known bug in iTunes connect , I contacted the apple support team and they got it fixed within 2 days

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's a known bug in iTunes connect , I contacted the apple support team and they got it fixed within 2 days

Answer (score 11):

You can goto your apps page with the address:

https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps

But first login via:

https://developer.apple.com

Answer (score 3):

For the first time you open iTunes connect, it should be opened from the [apple developer account](https://developer.apple.com/account)

to agree for the terms.

[image]